# How to update file1's variable from file2 without importing file2 into file1?

Tags: python, import, dependencies, global-variables

I have three files, ICML.py, minimization.py, and eval.py.

ICML.py imports a variable named "MINIMIZE" from minimization.py, and eval.py imports a class from ICML.py

I would like to create a loop that updates "MINIMIZE" and then runs a function "evaluate()" from eval.py. I cannot import that function into the minimization file, as that creates a circular dependency.

So I created a new file, eval_min.py, that imports "MINIMIZE" from minimization.py and imports "evaluate()" from eval.py. However, when I update "MINIMIZE" in this file, it does not update in ICML.py, but I need it to. I cannot import eval_min.py into ICML.py because of circular dependency. What do I do?

I've tried various imports of specific variables and functions but they always result in a circular import error.

Comment: How do you expect that we will be able to help, without showing any actual code??

Comment: What do you mean by “ it does not update in ICML.py”? When you import MINIMIZE in eval_min.py you are creating a different instance of that variable. You would need to pass it from eval_min.py to the function in ICML.py

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you were doing something like this:

```
from minimization import MINIMIZE
MINIMIZE = 5
```

... but that doesn't work, because that just rebinds the name `MINIMIZE` as a new *local* variable, and it no longer refers to the value inside the `minimization` module.

If you want to update a variable *inside another module*, then do it this way:

```
import minimization
minimization.MINIMIZE = 5
```

This maintains the connection to the `minimization` module.